# Open source C/C++ 3d renderer (with support of 3ds max models)

Tags: c++, c, rendering, 3dsmax

Best, smallest, fastest, open source, C/C++ 3d renderer (with support of 3ds max models), better not GPL,

It should support Lights, textures (better dynamic), simple objects, It should be really fast and it shall have lots of use examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise Ogre, it's pretty mature and really good API.

[Ogre license](http://www.ogre3d.org/licensing)

there is a plugin to export 3DSMax model to the orgre format [there](http://www.walkerfamily.name/lexiexport.php).

Answer (score 0):

[Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) for example

zlib/libpng license

Very good documentation